# Python - Display Excel database in a grid

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pygame, grid-layout

I am an archaeologist processing results from an excavation trench that is laid out in a 6x6 square grid - each square is 5 m x 5 m.
I want to plot the distribution of the finds found in the excavation on the grid.

I want to display some Excel database values in a 6x6 Python/Pygame grid.
Would someone please tell me **how I should go about doing this?**
I think I know how to get Python to read an Excel document in `*.csv` but I can't display it in a grid.

**Edit about Data**
A Snippet of the data can be found in the link. I would like to display the items from the 'classification' column in the grid. 
http://i48.tinypic.com/2rdgn02.jpg

**For example,**
The number of 'preparation flakes' in each square either as numbers or as colours/shapes, where each square coresponds to the gridsquare number in column S. The database is getting quite large.
So,
Ideally I would like the program to read the database and update the square without me having to continually change the program.

The code is now as follows.

```
<import csv
 import os

 import pygame

# the functions for display
def disp(phrase,loc,screen):   # function to display phrase at loc on surface.
     s = font.render(phrase, True, (255,255,255))
     screen.blit(s, loc) #

def text_display_csv(filename,surface):
    '''Display .csv file contents on surface'''
    f = csv.reader(open("Flint catalogue v1.7 4 Feb 13 2013.csv")) # open the csv file      in one line!

    for row in f:
        y = f.line_num                # assign y as Row no.
        for x,item in enumerate(row): # Get column number(x) and item
        disp(item, (64*x+10,64*y+10), surface) # display item



pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier",36) # font initialisation
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


# the part you want to see
text = [str(i) for i in range(36)] # raw data!
text_display_csv(text,screen) # text is displayed
pygame.display.update() # screen updated

# Main loop, does nothing! :)
running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
             pygame.quit()
             break
         if not running:
            break
```

If It is possible. i would like the results to be displayed in a fashion similar to the pic bellow where each number represents the number of 'preperation flakes in the square.
http://i49.tinypic.com/f39hxv.png

I am very grateful for any help and please say if this doesn't make sense

Tom

Comment: Could you give some example data and a rough image of how the result should look like?

Comment: sorry i havnt been as clear as i should have been. i shall add some more stuff to the description

Comment: apparently im not allowed to add pics which is annoying. sorry about that.

Comment: *sample data* classification - preperation flake;    colour-blue;    patina - white;    context - 3667;   Grid Suare - 5;

Comment: @TomLawrence Host the image on a free image hosting service and paste the link to the image in the question.

Comment: all done!!! Thanks. Is what i want to do clear enough or should i change the description still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't told us what kind of data you are using,
I have taken integers but any string will work.

Here's how you can display
**A Grid containing strings** (numbers in this case) **in Pygame:**

```
import pygame

# the functions for display
def disp(phrase,loc,screen):   # function to display phrase at loc on surface.
    s = font.render(phrase, True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(s, loc) #

def text_display(data,surface):
    '''display your data(list/tuple),containing strings on surface'''
    for x in range(6):         # your data is in 6 X 6 grid
        for y in range(6):
            disp( data[x+(y*6)], (64*x+10,64*y+10), surface)
            # 64 is the distance between 2 strings and 10 is the offset

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier",36) # font initialisation
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

text = [str(i) for i in range(36)] # raw data!
text_display(text,screen) # text is displayed
pygame.display.update() # screen updated

# Main loop, does nothing! :)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            break
    if not running:
        break
```

### This results in

[image: Grid image]

---

**Update**
Well Tom,
For the csv file, you can add this function to the script, and use it instead of `text_display`

```
def text_display_csv(filename,surface):
    '''Display .csv file contents on surface'''
    f = csv.reader(open(filename)) # open the csv file in one line!

    for row in f:
        y = f.line_num                # assign y as Row no.
        for x,item in enumerate(row): # Get column number(x) and item
            disp(item, (64*x+10,64*y+10), surface) # display item
```

I haven't tested it, So please tell me whether it works or not.

**Update 2**
In the first code block, add the `text_display_csv` and

Change

```
text = [str(i) for i in range(36)] # raw data!
text_display(text,screen) # text is displayed
pygame.display.update() # screen updated
```

to

```
filename = 'the .csv file'
text_display_csv(filename,screen) # text is displayed
pygame.display.update() # screen updated
```

So that the code works. (change the spacings and offsets if needed)

Comment: Thanks for this! its really useful!!! so for the program to dispaly the excel data i would change 'disp( data[x+(y*6)], (64*x+10,64*y+10), surface)' to something that includes 'c = csv.reader(open("lym12 bedrock data1.csv"))
for row in c:
     row[2]'   ?????????

Comment: @TomLawrence See the update, It answers that. Also, use ` not ' for `code` in comments or for variable names in questions. (it's the key beside 1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't quite work.. error says text_display is not defined

Comment: Use `text_display_csv` not `text_display` !!

Comment: yep i did. i will look over it again to double check

Comment: The code seems to work in a way. i have added a pic of what the result is in the original post....which is a bit baffling to me

Comment: @TomLawrence Could you ask another question on your new problem? My answer is already very long.